# Null Pointer Exception in Reading file from resources java

Tags: java, maven, file, resources

I'm trying to read a .csv file from my resource folder in my maven project.
I've done it before like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResource("info.csv").openStream()));

CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader,
CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());
```

and it worked. and now in another project, I'm trying read my file from resources and I get NullPointerException.

The only thing that is different between these 2 projects is my packages.

This is for the one that works:

[image]

and This is the one that doesn't work:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After fix by @jens answer, sure that resource's file is exist at target folder. If not, compile before

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a slash before the filename:

```
new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResource("/info.csv").openStream()));
```

without slash it looks in the same directory structure than your class is located

Comment: @MikhailIonkin it is an maven Project and will be copied by maven